# Tags are not written in influxdb through kafka-connect-influxdb

Tags: apache-kafka, influxdb, apache-kafka-connect

I am trying to connect kafka sink to influxdb. While it works but it does not save tags. For example if i send this to kafka topic

```
{"id": 1, "product": "pencil", "quantity": 100, "price": 50, "tags" : {"DEVICE": "living", "location": "home"}}`
```

Data is saved to influxdb but only the fields part.

[image]

I have been trying to debug this but failed. The versions i am using:

```
kafka 2.11-2.4.0
influxdb: 1.7.7
```

Comment: confluent version 5.5.1

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this too when I followed the Avro tags example on this page:

https://docs.confluent.io/kafka-connect-influxdb/current/influx-db-sink-connector/index.html

The "tags" schema in the example was incorrect. The example defines tags as:

```
{
    "name": "tags",
    "type": {
        "name": "tags",
        "type": "record",
        "fields": [{
            "name": "DEVICE",
            "type": "string"
        }, {
            "name": "location",
            "type": "string"
        }]
    }
}
```

It should actually be

```
{
  "name": "tags",
  "type": {
    "type": "map",
    "values": "string"
  }
}
```

This web page provided the solution: https://rmoff.net/2020/01/23/notes-on-getting-data-into-influxdb-from-kafka-with-kafka-connect/